# Get a gps navigatable file from a Google map available on a website

Tags: google-maps, kml, gpx

I am trying to download this - http://googlemapkml.publishpath.com/Websites/googlemapkml/files/Content/5880032/GEDriving66.htm - map on to my phone. My end goal is to be able to drive on this route, so it would be great if this map could be opened on my phone (Android) and I could get GPS-assisted navigation.

I am totally new to these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download this file from that website to your phone https://sites.google.com/site/route66maptour/goggle-earth/GEdrive.kml
Google Maps Android or iOS as far as I know does not let you load a KML. You can use another mapping application and load the KML and follow it.